# strip - solve dtd error SSIS using xml /xsd file

Tags: xml, ssis, xsd, ssis-2012

I have written a SSIS package that uses an xml source (saved as .XSD)

I made a normal package that just brought back data for countries from a HTTP website

the one I have is HTTPS hence I am getting DTD error.

1. As it HTTPS I don't know how to amend my script task to authenticate the username and password. I am only basic with SSIS . Please see 1. coding , myself trying is currently // out.
2. is the XML file saved as and XSD file type, code provided below. What can I add to the xml code to stop the DTD error

   1. public void Main()
      {

      ```
      string xmlDoc = String.Empty;

      try
      {
          // Get the URL from the variable
          string url = Dts.Variables["User::URL"].Value.ToString();
          // Get the Email from the variable
          // string Email = Dts.Variables["User::username"].Value.ToString();
         // Get the Password from the variable
         //string Password = Dts.Variables["User::Password"].Value.ToString();

          //Create a Web Client
          using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
          {
              //Download the xml document as a string
              xmlDoc = client.DownloadString(url);
          }

          // Set the value of the xmlDocument to the string that was just downloaded
          Dts.Variables["User::xmlDoc"].Value = xmlDoc;

          Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
      }
      catch
      {
          Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
      }
      }
      ```

   please help 2.

   Here is the start of my xml document ..saved as xsd

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
   <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

   <xs:element name="events">
   ```

Comment: What is the error message or error code that you're getting?

Comment: [XML Source [28]] Error: The XML Source was unable to read the XML data. DTD is prohibited in this XML document.
@digital.aaron

Comment: I think the problem is that an .XSD is a document that defines the "shape" of the xml, and is used for validating an .XML document. XML Source is expecting the .XML document, not its definition.